# Printing the value of memory allocated by calloc not initialized to zeroed

Tags: c, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm confused about what is happening when I try to use `calloc` as opposed to `malloc`. My understanding is that `calloc` allocates the memory and initializes the value at each address to zero, whereas `malloc` just allocates the memory. However, when I attempt to print the values at each address I expect the values to be zero for `calloc` and random characters for `malloc` - But they aren't... they're the same no matter which I do.

```
typedef struct {
    char* text;
    void* obj;
} statement_t;

void* stalloc() {
    return calloc(1, MODEL_OBJ_CAPACITY);
    // return malloc(MODEL_OBJ_CAPACITY); Also used this
};

statement_t NewStatement(char* text) {
    statement_t statement;
    statement.text = text;
    statement.obj = stalloc();

    return statement;
};


int main(void) {
    statement_t statement = NewStatement("CREATE job Manager");

    for(int n = 0; n < 10; ++n) {
        printf("statement[%d]: %c\n", n, (char)&statement.obj[n]); // Note I've tried a number of ways to print this but they always end up being the same
    }

    ...
}
```

Output from `calloc`:

```
statement: CREATE job Manager 0x7fb127405c60 8
statement[0]: `
statement[1]: a
statement[2]: b
statement[3]: c
statement[4]: d
statement[5]: e
statement[6]: f
statement[7]: g
statement[8]: h
statement[9]: i
```

Output from `malloc`:

```
statement: CREATE job Manager 0x7f8becc05c60 8
statement[0]: `
statement[1]: a
statement[2]: b
statement[3]: c
statement[4]: d
statement[5]: e
statement[6]: f
statement[7]: g
statement[8]: h
statement[9]: i
```

As you can see, they are the same... What am I missing?

Comment: what is `statement_t` ?

Comment: What is ```MODEL_OBJ_CAPACITY``` ? How much ```calloc()``` is allocating is pretty important.

Comment: `statement.text = text`... are you sure you don't want to copy it?

Comment: I don't think these are random values - notice the first value corresponds to `0x60`, the next to `0x61`, etc.

Comment: I notice you aren't checking to see if the memory was successfully allocated or not.  You should check the pointer returned before you dereference it.

Comment: Pro tip: notice that those are clearly not random values, but sequential. Also that the UTF-8/ASCII value of `\`` is 0x60 which just so happens to be  the low byte of the address you print just before attempting to print the memory.

Comment: @0___________ I edited to show `statement_t`

Comment: @Zakk `MODEL_OBJ_CAPACITY` is set to 10

Comment: This code is illegal, you cannot use `[]` on `void *` in Standard C. Please invoke compiler in conforming mode to avoid wasting time with runtime errors on programs that should be rejected at compile-time

Comment: @M.M gcc allows it

Comment: @0___________ This code is illegal, you cannot use [] on void * in **Standard C**. Please invoke compiler **in conforming mode** to avoid wasting time with runtime errors on programs that should be rejected at compile-time

Comment: @M.M did you read my comment? gcc has it as an extension

Comment: @0___________ Cool story

Comment: @M.M makes a good point, it's a waste of everyone's time to troubleshoot problems that the compiler already found. To prevent this, I would advise to follow [What compiler options are recommended for beginners learning C?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/282565) And suddenly we get _"ISO C does not allow extra ';' outside of a function"_, _" error: pointer of type 'void *' used in arithmetic"_ and a tonne of other errors, most of them self-explanatory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`obj` has type of `void*`. C standard does not allow any pointer arithmetics on void pointers. There is not possible to index `void *`.

It is is a `gcc` extension and it is not portable.

Try:

```
printf("statement[%zu]: %d\n", n, ((char *)statement.obj)[n]);
```

or

```
    int c;

    for(size_t n = 0; n < 10; ++n) {
        c = ((char *)statement.obj)[n];
        printf("statement[%zu]: %s : %d (0x%02x)\n", n, (c >= 32 && c <= 127) ? (char []){'\'', c, '\'', 0} : "not printable", c, c ); 
    }
```

Comment: What does having a set of parens around `(char *)statement.obj` do?

Comment: It shows the compiler that I index `char *` pointer

Comment: Ok so this does what expected for `calloc` in that it prints 0 for each, but it also does the same when using `malloc`. Is that correct? I though `malloc` allocates but there would be characters in those memory blocks whereas `calloc` allocates and inits them to zero, hence why they print print 0s

Comment: @Garrett with malloc it is not determined. Any value is possible. No rules.

Comment: Ahh ok so in other words it is ok that the printed outs are the same and in the future printing after using `malloc` may end up doing what I had expected from this question?

Comment: @Garrett I have no idea what you mean. malloc - undetermined, calloc - zeroed. No more or less. You can try to force your theories and write invalid programs assuming that malloc also zeroes the memory. I would not

Comment: When you said before `It shows the compiler that I index char * pointer` you mean it's showing the compiler that we actually want to get the value at that location in memory?

Comment: It does dereference the pointer

Answer (score 0):

You're not printing correctly:

```
printf("statement[%d]: %c\n", n, (char)&statement.obj[n]);
```

You're attempting to print the *address* of each byte in the array, rather than the byte itself.  Also, by using `%c` you're printing the character associated with each byte value instead of the actual value.

First cast the `void *` to `char *`, then index the array.  Also, use `%d` to print the value of each byte:

```
printf("statement[%d]: %d\n", n, ((char *)statement.obj)[n]);
```

Comment: OP is maybe confusing `printf` with `scanf`. The `%d` and `%c` format specifiers require pointer values in `scanf`, but not in `printf`.

Comment: I had this originally, it give error `incomplete type is not allowed`

Comment: @dbush how can you index void * (except gcc)

Comment: trying to print a char of value `0` with `%c` is not well-defined

Comment: @0___________ Must have overlooked the pointer type.  Fixed.

Comment: @M.M Good point, not to mention ambiguous for some values.  Changed to use `%d`.